# Cannot react to click event in Electron app

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have packaged my HTML+CSS+JS app into an executable using Electron, however it doesn't work the same way as it does in a browser. Specifically, my app doesn't seem to react to click events, whereas if I run the app in a browser, the click event gets caught no problem.

Here's how I structured my app. In a file called `index.html` I have the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   ...
    <script src="js/default.js"></script>
   ...
</head>
<body onload="prepareGame()">
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

The function `prepareGame()`, which is defined inside `js/default.js`, is where I add a click listener to an element of the DOM:

```js
function prepareGame() {
    ...
    gameArea.addEventListener('click', clickListener);
}
```

where `clickListener` is also defined in `js/default.js` and is the function that I want to execute upon a click event.
The problem is that `clickListener` does not get executed when I click on the element for which I registered a listener. Even more strange is the fact that `prepareGame()` does get executed (I've checked that by putting an `alert()` inside of it), and so does the line `gameArea.addEventListener('click', clickListener);`, however `clickListener()` doesn't get called when I click on the element. 
Notice that I don't have this problem when I run my app on a browser, i.e. `clickListener()` gets executed when I click on the element.

I honestly don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it like this using script and not events in the HTML.

I don't know how you initialise the gameArea object, but here we get it when the DOM is ready.

```js
let gameArea;

const clickListener = ({ target }) => {
  console.log(target.innerHTML);
};

const prepareGame = () => {  
    // set gameArea now DOM is ready
    gameArea = document.querySelector('.gameArea');
    gameArea.addEventListener('click', clickListener);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  prepareGame();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body class="gameArea">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, despite I had no time to test your solution, I suspect that it wouldn't work. The point is that `prepareGame()` does get executed (I know that for certain), but `clickListener()` does not. I have edited my question to make that point clearer